# Using wget via Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webserver, wget

I want to build a simple website that can download a webpage `www.example.com/index.html` and store its snapshot on the server when the client requests. I'm thinking about using the command `wget` to download the webpage. Would Ruby on Rails be able to handle this task?

Comment: By snapshot, do you mean a picture, or the underlying html?

Comment: Ah, I mean both the underlying html and any pictures/stylesheets associated with that page (i.e. using the -p option of wget.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes.

You can perform [shell commands in Ruby via back ticks, exec and system](http://rubyquicktips.com/post/5862861056/execute-shell-commands).  Note that each one returns something slightly different:

1. back ticks

   ```
   `wget http://www.yahoo.com`
   ```
2. `exec`:

   ```
   exec('wget http://www.yahoo.com')
   ```
3. `system`:

   ```
   system('wget http://www.yahoo.com')
   ```

[This blog post](http://blogforever.eu/blog/2011/05/21/creating-a-snapshot-of-a-blog-post-using-wget/) seems to be in the same vein as what you're trying to do.

Additionally, there are several terrific Ruby libraries for doing this:

1. [mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/) with [mechanize download](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/Download.html) - check out this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/191-mechanize)
2. [httparty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) - simple wrapper around a [more-difficult-to-use http library](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html).  Once you get the response body, you will need to save it to the database or file.
3. [typhoeus](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus) - simple mechanism for making the http requests in parallel, if you need such an ability

They will provide a much better cleaner Ruby interface for dealing with the data that comes back from the various requests.

---

The best way to test all of these options is to use the Rails console.  Go to the root directory of your Rails app and type:

```
rails c
```

Once in the console, you can emulate the actual server calls.

Running `wget` in your console will drop the files in your Rails root directory, which is not what you want. `tmp` is a standard directory for such things.  You can dynamically generate the path based on the URL like so:

```
# tmp directory
path = Rails.root.join('tmp')
# create sub-directory as md5 hash based on URL
sub_dir = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(url)
# append sub_dir on the path
destination_path = path.join(sub_dir) 
system("wget -P #{destination_path} #{url}")
```

Be sure to also include the options from [this post](http://blogforever.eu/blog/2011/05/21/creating-a-snapshot-of-a-blog-post-using-wget/)

Comment: Thanks! Let me take some time to go through your answer.
By the way, once I execute `wget` using `exec`/`system`, how can I specify where on the server to place the files?

Comment: [The blog post](http://blogforever.eu/blog/2011/05/21/creating-a-snapshot-of-a-blog-post-using-wget/) you mentioned is absolutely incredible. This should pretty much replace half the static page parser ruby gems out there obsolete.