# Ruby Storing wget output in a variable

Tags: ruby, wget

I am using the `-O` or `--output-document` option on `wget` to store get the http from a website. However the -O option requires a file for the output to be stored in and I would like to store it in a variable in my program so that I can manipulate it easier. Is there any way to do this without rereading it in from the file? In essence, I am manually creating a crude cache.

**Sample code**

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
url= "http://www.google.com"
whereIWantItStored = `wget #{url} --output-document=outsideFile`
```

**Reference**:
I found this post helpful in using `wget` within my program: [Using wget via Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789369/using-wget-via-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: result = `wget #{url}  -O -`  

Make sure that url is not user supplied, to avoid shell injection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
url= "http://www.google.com"
whereIWantItStored = `wget #{url} -O -`
```

Be sure to sanitize your url to avoid shell injection.      The - after -O means standard output, which gets captured by the ruby backticks.

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Command_Injection  explains shell injection.

http://apidock.com/ruby/Shellwords/shellescape  For Ruby >=1.9  or the [Escape Gem](http://www.a-k-r.org/escape/) for ruby 1.8.x

Comment: BRILLIANT!! Cant tell how many times I tried that yet I left the `=` sign between the option and the dash. Replacing it with a space solves the issue. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Can you also give me a reference page so I can look more into sanitizing my url?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use wget.  I'd use something like [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty).

Then you could do:

```
require 'httparty'
url = 'http://www.google.com'
response = HTTParty.get(url)

whereIWantItStored = response.code = 200 ? response.body : nil
```

Comment: To make sure the page was returned correctly.  A 500 code would be an error response, a 404 code would be a page not found.